# Incorrect collision? SpriteKit

Tags: ios, physics, collision, skphysicsbody

I'm making a game in which there are horizontal rectangles falling down and a ball in the scene, when the ball collides with the rectangle the moveTo action for the rectangle should stop. This [node removeAllActions] is the first thing called in the didbegincontact method. This should basically freeze the frame when the contact starts so the ball and recitingle should be in contact.

But this is not the some 50% of the time: here is an example: 
[image]

I enabled the view physics option and the physics body fits tightly with the ball so I don't think the physics body for the ball is wrong.

I have enabled usesPreciseCollisionDetection for the ball only

Is this just a lag in the game calling the removeAllActions?

Please help thanks

Comment: there's an invisible threshold around each collision shape, you can only control it by making the shapes of bodies a bit smaller

Comment: Did you try setting the usesPreciseCollisionDetection on the blocks as well?